# Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider Version 3.0.2 does not support .Net Framework 4?

Tags: .net-4.0, firebird

I downloaded Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider 3.0.2 from the Firdbird website.

```
http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/
```

I start a new visual studio project, specifying .Net Framework 4 (not client profile)

At the top of one of my source files I put

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
```

Then I try to build the project, and it gives the following error -

```
The type or namespace name 'FirebirdSql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

However if I download version 2.6 of the Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider, it works just fine.

Am I understanding this correctly, version 3.0.2 does not support .NET Framework 4.0?

Unfortunately Windows Xp doesn't support .NET 4.5 so I hope that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the "NET40" version and reference this.

Comment: I did that, it doesn't fix it.

Comment: @NoPyGod Check that you reference the (right) assembly in your project.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, when I was at work I downloaded the NET40 version mentioned above and compared it to the version I was already referencing, it was the same identical size and version. I just tried it at home and it works, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with the GAC cache.

Comment: Thanks guys, re-adding the reference to the NET40 version worked. Nothing to do with GAC cache. My dumb mistake I guess.